# How to compute the chances of wining on this game?

Tags: statistics, gambling

In a game, you start with K coins. On each turn, a coin is flipped. If heads, you gain a coin; if tails, you lose one coin. Turns are played continuously until either you have 0 coins (you lost), or `K + X` coins, for a fixed X (you won).

How can I calculate the probability `P(K, X)` of losing/winning?

Comment: The gain/loss of a coin can be represented by a random walk, which gives a normal distribution around K. You are interested in the probability of the "random-walker" to reach either 0 (K away from starting point) or K+X (X away). Hope that helps the further investigation.

Comment: Oh, that is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the coin flips are fair, your expected number of coins must always remain the same: $K$.  Let the probability of winning (i.e., reaching $K+X$ before reaching $0$) be $P_{K,X}$.  Then
$$
K = P_{K,X}\cdot (K+X) + (1-P_{K,X})\cdot 0,
$$
or
$$
P_{K,X} = \frac{K}{K+X}.
$$